# Spatial index search that returns sorted results

Tags: sorting, search-algorithms

I need to perform a spatial index search while also sort the results by one of the dimensions.

**Backstory:**

I have a map with lots of 2D objects and when the user interacts with the map I need to filter only those objects that are inside the screen rectangle and at a visible distance (not bigger than the whole screen, not smaller than a single pixel). To do this, I want to use a 3D R-tree library.

I do not understand the math but I found [a library](https://github.com/Eronana/rbush-3d) that perfectly suits my needs, so far so good.

But things get complicated. Sometimes I need to draw labels for map objects that are so small they not even visible. The user will see the label and he will zoom to the object. ([This is not a regular map](https://us.wikibudgets.org/w/united-states-budget-2016)). So I filter all objects that are inside the screen rectangle, are smaller than the whole screen and bigger than 0. So far so good. To draw only labels that do not overlap I will use another spatial index tree (2D). But I need to start drawing labels for the big object first, drawing labels for smaller objects only if there is a space on the screen. That means I need the results of the 3D spatial search sorted by the Z distance (or Z size).

The number of results from the spatial search can be huge, simply calling a sort function is not feasible. I could sort all the objects by Z size during initialization, but then won't know which are inside the screen rectangle. I need to somehow combine the efficiency of the R-tree with the ability to have sorted results.

**Is there a variant of [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) that will return search (intersection) results sorted by one of the dimensions, efficiently?**